# QGis Standalone App access to maptools defined in app directory

Tags: qgis, c++

I'm developing an QGIS application estandalone in c ++, and would like to know why the "app" directory, the QGIS source code is not exposed. As I would like to use some of the Tools that there are defined.
It can be done in any way? Which would be the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in the "app" library is not exposed as public API - it generally just contains the non-reusable portions of GUI and GUI logic, and accordingly isn't a stable api and changes between releases. Unfortunately there's occasionally some code (such as some of the map tools) which reside in app but should ideally be generalised and moved to the GUI library.

There's two solutions:

1. copy and paste the code across to your app
2. (better!) clone the QGIS repo, move these classes to gui, and open a pull request to the main QGIS repo so that everyone can benefit from your work.

Comment: thanks @ndawson, these options are I had in mind to develop. And I agree that Option 2 is the best.
In the organization I work we need to make an app based on QGIS and depend on the upgrade process.
Therefore, Option 2 would be more appropriate.